# Is there an uncrustify option to prevent aligning on the end paren?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, formatting, xcode6, uncrustify

How do I prevent uncrustify from aligning my method definitions on the end paren?

I have this interface file

```
@import UIKit;

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

@required
- (BOOL)isEditing;
- (BOOL)isValid;
- (NSInteger)numberOfItems;
- (id<MyItemProtocol>)itemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (NSDictionary*)toDictionary;

@end
```

And uncrustify aligns all the methods on the end paren like this:

```
@import UIKit;

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

@required
- (BOOL)              isEditing;
- (BOOL)              isValid;
- (NSInteger)         numberOfItems;
- (id<MyItemProtocol>)itemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (NSDictionary*)     toDictionary;

@end
```

Which option can I set to prevent this?

It might be worth noting that if there is a newline between each method then uncrustify does not try to align them.